How can I remove a post snapped below concrete?
I want to remove residual 4x4 wood post from concrete base, but the remaining wood is solidly lodged in. The post snapped just below the surface and I got most of it out.
Any tips to break up and remove the remaining wood? Rather than dig up the concrete, I’d like to just clear the path and drop the new post in.

Hire some termites? But seriously: Pictures would help.

Set it on fire....or get 24 inch long drill, and drill it out

If you got most of it out then what is the problem?

So you've experienced "why setting wood posts in concrete is bad for the life of the post" but you want to repeat the experience? If you're going to set the post in concrete, buy a galvanized, stainless, or cor-ten steel post. Or a steel post base that a wooden post bolts to above the ground.

Why do you want to remove the wood?  What condition is it in?  Presumably you want to keep and reuse the concrete base, but to what end (for a new post?).  More info, pic please, so we can be of more help.

Use stump remover, or just burn it out.

Or this? How can I repair a snapped 4x4 mailbox post without digging out the footing?

Or this? How do I replace a wooden fence post that was set in concrete?
